# Vector Dot Product of Zero

Tags: linear-algebra

What can be said about two vectors that have a dot product equal to zero? Say

$$\overrightarrow a = <1,1,1>,\quad 
\overrightarrow b = <1,-1,0>, $$
wher
$\overrightarrow a \cdot \overrightarrow b = 0.$

I believe that vector $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b $ are perpendicular to each other, meaning the vectors are orthogonal. Am I correct in assuming this or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: You are correct, a dot product of zero means orthogonal. Sometimes orthogonal is defined to be a dot product of zero, so that even if one of the vectors is zero, the two vectors are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the definition $\vec a \cdot \vec b = |\vec a||\vec b| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them.

There are three variables on the right hand side. So what are the possibilities that make that expression zero?

Comment: @MaartenHilferink That's what I meant. Sorry, my brain is at "cross" purposes from my fingers early in the morning.